# Which is the best way to send data between fragments? ViewModel or Destination Arguments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigation, android-viewmodel

Imagine that I have two fragments:

- FirstFragment
- SecondFragment

User will prompt some data in FirstFragment, and I'll like to share some of that data to SecondFragment. I'm using Android's ViewModel and Jetpack's Navigation. Which is the best way to pass data?

**ViewModel**

In the case of the viewModel, if I instantiate the viewModel like this:

```java
MyViewModel viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(MyViewModel.class);
```

in every fragment, I could create a method called `setSharedData` and call it from FirstFragment, and create methods to `getSpecificData` and call them as needed in my SecondFragment.

**Destination arguments**

If I use Jetpack's Navigation I could use [destination arguments with safe-args](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data) to share data, setting it in the actions between Fragments.

What option do you think is the best? Do you think those are different solutions that suit better for different situations? In that case, which method should I use in which situation?

Comment: Best way in which case?

Comment: In the example I described above. Also, I would like to know which option is better for some other possible cases

Answer (score 1):

I think the view model approach is useful when you want using the shared data multiple times but if you only need the shared data for initiating, i recommend to use the destination argument. Because persisting the data in the view model uses of memory and it isn't necessary.

Comment: In the case of the view model, when is the data going to be deleted from memory? After changing to another activity?

Comment: Yes. The memory of data will release when the view model is destroyed.